# List Element Tag mapping from XML to Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I need to migrate from **XML** to **Annotation** mappings on Hibernate 4.1.0. I can't find and equivalent for this XML mapping property.

```
<list name="series" lazy="false">
      <key column="query_id"/>
      <list-index column="position"/>
      <element column="xml_def" type="xml"/>
 </list>
```

Here's the annotation mapping i started to wrote:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToMany
@OrderColumn(name = "position")
@JoinColumn(name = "query_id")
public List<Serie> getSeries() {
    return series;
}
```

But how can i migrate the **element** tag, to define a custom type for the elements of the collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use the @manyToMany annotation in your case cause your Serie object is not really an hibernate entity, it's just serialize as XML. Try this:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OrderColumn(name = "position")
@JoinTable(name = "yourTable", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "query_id"))
@Type(type = "xml")
@Column(name = "xml_def")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Serie.class)
@Override
public List<Serie> getSeries() {
    return series;
}
```

With this form you don't need to annotate your Serie object as Entity.